# Do I need a comma after an opposite alternative presented by "а не ..." phrase in a complex sentence?

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need a comma here before the word "было"?:

"Oдному Богу известно, насколько подлинным, а не показным, было моё смирение"

Comment: In fact, you need a comma before "насколько". This is сложноподчинённое предложение, where different parts of the sentence are connected, so you can ask question from one part to get the other one. "Одному богу известно" что? - "насколько подлинным …".
Sorry for making a comment in the answer, just don' have permission to comment.

Comment: "In fact, you need a comma before "насколько" - Oh yes! I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется): ***Не род, а ум*** *поставлю в воеводы (П.); Каждый вечер солнце садилось* ***в море, а не в тучи*** *и было при этом клюквенного цвета (Ю. К.); Они получили* ***небольшую, но удобную*** *квартиру; Поставлена* ***трудная, зато интересная*** *задача; Слышалась* ***жалобная, если не униженная*** *просьба пощадить его самолюбие; В кинофильме рассказывается о* ***первой, пусть неразделённой*** *любви; Получены* ***важные, хотя и не итоговые*** *сведения; У девочки* ***опасная, потому что заразная*** *болезнь.*

Д. Э. Розенталь
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО РУССКОМУ ЯЗЫКУ: ОРФОГРАФИЯ И ПУНКТУАЦИЯ

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for asking. I needed my memory refreshed on this rule myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need a comma before "было".
It is a сложноподчинённое предложение, where main part = "Одному Богу известно", dependent part = "насколько подлинным, а не показным было моё смирение". This implies that the comma before "насколько" is needed.
The comma before "а не" is needed because words "подлинным" и "показным" are opposed by "а не".
But no other commas.